# Different default merge methods for different branches?

Tags: github

I’d love to be able to set two different default merge methods for two different branches, if possible. For `main` I’d love for it to always default to “Squash and merge,” and for any branch name matching `milestone/[0-9]*/*` I’d love for it to be “Create a merge commit”.

Is this possible within GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

*Reposted with more details since last answer got deleted as duplicate.*

There's currently no way to set default merge strategy on GitHub branches (nor on repos or organizations), and I didn't find any feature requests for it either. So I made a feature request for chenging the default merge strategy for all three (branches, repos, orgs) here: https://github.com/github-community/community/discussions/20583

Please go vote and comment if you agree with the suggested feature(s)